# If condition of Big 0 notation for different values for constants on the same functions

Tags: big-o, proof

we define big-O notation as follows: `f(x) = O(g(x))` if there 
    exist positive constants `M` and `x0` such that `f(x) <= M g(x)` for all **`x > x0`**.
    I am now defining a new version of big-O notation: `f(x) = O'(g(x))` if there
    exist positive constants `M'` and `x0'`
    such that `f(x) <= M'g(x)` for all **`x >= x0'`** (the difference being the non strict inequality `>=`).

Are these two definitions equivalent? In other words, if `f(x) = O(g(x))`, must
    it be the case that `f(x) = O'(g(x))`, and vice versa? Need Proof for the same

Comment: I may have missed something but I do not see any difference between the definitions apart from the notation

Comment: If your definitions are on general case, there are same definition because it is just a matter of symbols. You do not infer any value, just exitence of them. However, if you found two specific pairs [x0,M] [x0',M'] then your question has no real meaning since big O is defined by existence and not for specific values. However, if you define O' for specific case eand big  for general case, then the second implies the first but not the second of course (we can always find a case with a bigger M or x0. I do not see teh point in ths case however

Comment: I just edited the question . The difference being in the second definition f(x) = O'(g(x)) , there exists positive constants M' and x0' such that f(x) <= M'g(x) for all **x >= x0'**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. It would be on-topic on [math.se].

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both definitions are equivalent. Here is why:

If `f(x) <= Mg(x)` for all `x > x0`, then the same would hold for `x >= x0 + 1` (so you can take `x0 + 1` as the value of `x0'` in the definition of `O'`). Conversely, if the inequality holds for all `x >= x0'`, it will remain true for all `x > x0'` (and you can take `x0 = x0'` in the definition of `O`).

Comment: Thanks that answered the question precisely !